# Google Doc Viewer: Which formats are really supported?

Tags: iframe, google-docs, google-document-viewer

I'm using Google Docs Viewer to embed all kind of documents. However I am having trouble to find out which formats are really supported.

On the offical Docs Viewer website (https://docs.google.com/viewer) Google links to a nice list of all supported formats. The following formats should be supported:

- Google Docs
- Google Sheets
- Google Slides
- Google Forms
- Google Drawings
- Image files (.JPEG, .PNG, .GIF, .TIFF, .BMP)
- Raw Image formats
- Video files (WebM, .MPEG4, .3GPP, .MOV, .AVI,  .MPEGPS, .WMV, .FLV, .ogg)
- Microsoft Word (.DOC and .DOCX)
- Microsoft Excel (.XLS and .XLSX)
- Microsoft PowerPoint (.PPT and .PPTX)
- Adobe Portable Document Format (.PDF)
- Tagged Image File Format (.TIFF)
- Scalable Vector Graphics (.SVG)
- PostScript (.EPS, .PS)
- TrueType (.TTF)
- XML Paper Specification (.XPS)
- .MTS files

However, if I try to embed Image files or Video files for example I will get the famous 'Sorry, this type of document is not supported for viewing' error.

So my question is: Why doesn't it show these files and which formats are really supported?

Example: JPEG (not working)

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?embedded=true&amp;url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.fnordware.com%2Fj2k%2Frelax-orig.png
```

See for more examples: http://jsfiddle.net/ABcz6/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I can confirm that JPGs as well PNGs that I tried did not work. Originaly I was trying to view such files with Drupals *[Embedded Google Docs Viewer](https://www.drupal.org/project/gdoc_field)*, but then tested with just the URL `https://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=http://www.example.com/test.jpg`.

BUT, the semi-good news is that **you can use TIFF images instead**.

*Maybe TIFFs are just more office-stylee :D*

Comment: trying to put a tiff created in photoshop into a google results in "The image format is invalid or unsupported" in 2021

Comment: So what's the best solution for this?